# Why do we use one resistance in a potential divider, why not the other resistance?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider), like in the textbook I am using (Nelkon and Parker 7th edition), they decided to use Resistance 2 as the numerator. Why not resistance 1? I initially thought that the resistance choosen should depend on the direction of flow of conventional current, but my textbook does not consider this as a factor in deriving the ouput potential to be
$$I = \frac{V_0}{R_1 + R_2}$$
$$\implies V_1 = IR_1 = (\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2})V_0$$
In case my question has not been clear enough, why can't we have

$$V_1 = IR_2 = (\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2})V_0$$
From what I understood so far, this should depend on the direction of conventional current, but my textbook uses  a circuit diagram with a generic representation of a battery that hardly gives out information of the direction of conventional current flow, making me think that it is somehow irrelevant.

Comment: Which resistor is the output voltage taken across?

Comment: @d_b The output voltage is taken across $R_1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why can't we have
>
> $$V_1 = IR_2 = (\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2})V_0$$

You can*. The resistor on top is the one across which you are measuring the voltage. If you want $R_2$ on top then you just set up your leads so that you are measuring the voltage across $R_2$.

*when you do that you are measuring $V_2$, not $V_1$.

Comment: That was a simple but subtle detail. Thank you